# How to change the value of a "column" of a nested list in python?

Tags: python

In python 3, I have a nested list

```
my_list= [
   [2,2,2,2],
   [3,3,3,3],
   [4,4,4,4]
]
```

and I'd like to change all the values of the second column to `0`, to get

```
my_list= [
   [2,0,2,2],
   [3,0,3,3],
   [4,0,4,4]
]
```

Now, what I can do is

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i][1] = 0
```

but it doesn't seem to be very "pythonic", am I correct?
Is there a smarter way of doing it without using the  length of the array?

In Numpy I could use `my_list[:,2]=0`.

Comment: Can you give an example of the result that you want?

Comment: @AbhinavUpadhyay Edited the question to add  the example of the result.

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more pythonic way would be the following:

```
In [9]: for inner_list in my_list:
   ...:     inner_list[1] = 0
   ...:     

In [10]: my_list
Out[10]: [[2, 0, 2, 2], [3, 0, 3, 3], [4, 0, 4, 4]]
```

In Python when looping over lists or collections, you don't need to use `range(len(my_list))`, the `for` loop knows when to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  A more generic solution seems to be useful here.  What if you want to replace that column with another column ... that would be more like:

```
def replaceColumn(listOfLists, n, column):
    ''' Replace the "n"th column of the list of lists "table" source '''
    # Rotate the table...
    t = list(zip(*listOfLists))
    # Replace the (now) row
    t[n] = column
    # Rotate and return the table...
    return list(zip(*t))
```

Then the solution is more like:

```
replaceColumns(my_list, [0]*len(my_list), 1)
```

There is a side effect though: the rows end up as tuples!